# The Events Calendar EventURL not displaying

Tags: the-events-calendar

I have a custom footer with events being brought in. However, links are no longer showing while using tribe_get_event_meta. The link given is just my home url link and not the link to the event page. My link code is

```
<?php
global $post;
$i = 0;
$events = tribe_get_events( array(
 'posts_per_page' => 3,
  ));

  foreach ( $events as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post );
?>

  <a class="event-links" href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_meta( get_the_ID(), '_EventURL', true ); ?>" target="_self">
  <li class="evlist" id = "evli-<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <span class="evdate" id = "evspd-<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post, false, 'F j' );?>
  </span >
  <span class="evspan" id="evspanid-<?php echo $i;?>"><h2 class="evhead" id = "evspt-<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <?php echo "$post->post_title"; ?>:</h2 >
  <?php echo  tribe_events_get_the_excerpt( $post );?>
  </span >
</li >
</a>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem likely results from the `tribe_events_get_the_excerpt()` function calling `wp_reset_postdata()`, which resets the **global** `$post` object back to the original query (i.e., the page the footer is on). `get_the_ID()` returns the ID of the global `$post` object, so you will get the page’s ID instead of the event’s from within the loop. And `setup_postdata()` does **not** assign the global `$post` variable.

Simpliest solution in this case should be to replace `get_the_ID()` with `$post->ID` (`$post` referring to the loop’s local event value here, not the global):

```
<?php echo tribe_get_event_meta( $post->ID, '_EventURL', true ); ?>
```